# jsp Passing js Array variable as an Additional parameter in HTML <form action=" ">

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, jsp, action

I have a `html table` with lots of `checkbox` in the last column of the table and which looks like this
[image]

The HTML for processing on click of submit button is like this

```
<form action="/chbs/adm/HallNamesValidation.jsp?chkb=jsFacilitiesArray" method="post">
  <table id="hallTable">
    <tbody>
      <td><input type="text" id="hall_location" name="hall_location" onchange="rowEdited($(this).parent())" class="form-control"></input>
      </td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 125px; font-weight: normal;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="arrFacilities" name="arrFacilities" onchange="rowEdited($(this).parent())" class="facilityList"></input>
        <input type="checkbox" id="arrFacilities" name="arrFacilities" onchange="rowEdited($(this).parent())" class="facilityList"></input>
        <input type="checkbox" id="arrFacilities" name="arrFacilities" onchange="rowEdited($(this).parent())" class="facilityList"></input>
        <input type="checkbox" id="arrFacilities" name="arrFacilities" onchange="rowEdited($(this).parent())" class="facilityList"></input>
      </td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

The `js code` of `rowedited()` looks like this

```
function rowEdited(thistd) {
    var facilityString = "";
    $(tr).find("td:eq(5) input:checkbox").each(function(){
        facilityString = facilityString  + $(this).is(':checked') + ', ';
    });
    jsFacilitiesArr [currentRow] = facilityString;

    currentRow = null;  
};
```

I want to pass the Array `jsFacilitiesArr` of the above js function along with the `<form action=" ...>`. I couldn't find a solution, so am requesting here for assistance.

PS: I Tried this but I know this is not correct

```
<form action="/chbs/adm/HallNamesValidation.jsp?chkb=jsFacilitiesArray" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Place jsFacilitiesArr in a data-attribute on form and read it in rowEdited function.

Comment: Can you explain how to do it? the `rowEdited()` is invoked when `checkbox` is `clicked`. So there is nothing to read it in this function. This function generates the `jsFacilitiesArr ` array which I want to pass along with `<form action=""..`

Comment: In this case, you should try to create hidden input field inside form, which will be submitted along with the form.
Or you can serialize jsFacilitiesArr and update form action URL, to get data via GET request

Answer (score 0):

The Answer Given by @Pankaj is incorrect. I did more Googling and Searched more pages of Stackoverflow.com and arrived at the following solution.

just a line above `<table>` I placed the following `HTML`

```
<input type="hidden" id="jsFacilitiesArray" name="jsFacilitiesArray" value="" />
```

In js code of the rowEdited() function, I added the following statements

```
jsFacilitiesArr [currentRow] = facilityString;
$('#jsFacilitiesArray').val(JSON.stringify(jsFacilitiesArr));
```

In the `HallNamesValidation.jsp`, I have used following Statements to get the values

```
String facilitiesStr = request.getParameter("jsFacilitiesArray");
out.println(facilitiesStr);
```

That's It. Nothing more, Nothing Less. No Need to Import any library for this.
The Result as I desired is

```
["true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, ","true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, "]
```

To Convert this to an Array, I improvised the above code as follows:

```
String facilitiesStr = (request.getParameter("jsFacilitiesArray")).replace(", \"]","").replace("[\"","");
        String[] facArr = facilitiesStr.split("\",\"");
        //out.println(facArr);
     for (int i = 0; i <  facArr.length; i++) {

        out.println( facArr[i] + " NEXT "); 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your form action attribute inside `rowEdited` function

```
$("form#myForm").action = "/chbs/adm/HallNamesValidation.jsp?chkb=" + JSON.stringify(jsFacilitiesArr)
```

Please add some id or class to form to be easier to find it.